# js как загружать аудио файл уже во время работы сайта

Tags: javascript, async-await, асинхронность, загрузка

Мне нужно повесить аудио на одно событие. Для этого хочу загрузить это аудио в переменную

```
audio = new Audio(url);
```

Но данное аудио нужно не в самом начале загрузки сайта. А например секунд через 30 его работы. Поэтому хотелось бы, чтобы сам сайт загрузился, а аудио загружалось уже в фоне, чтобы загрузка страницы не стала медленнее. Как это реализовать? Придумал такой вариант, но не уверен в его правильности и не уверен, что вообще понял суть этого метода, поэтому и спрашиваю

```
/*Код который нужен для работы сайта и загружается сразу, используется с первой секунды*/
....
...
....
....
let audio = getAudio(url);
const getAudio = async url => {
  return await newAudio(url);
}
```

Comment: что мешает начать загружать по требованию _например секунд через 30 его работы_

Comment: @Grundy То что на его загрузку уйдет время. Я хочу чтобы он был заранее загружен и воспроизводился по мере необходимости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто, я дурак

> Если указан URL-адрес, браузер начинает асинхронно загружать медиаресурс перед возвратом нового объекта.

То есть, достаточно просто

```
let var = new Audio(src);
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
var audio = new Audio("sound.mp3"); // объявили и загрузили файл предварительно, чтобы потом на это не уходило время
setTimeout(function(){
    audio.play(); // воспроизводим по требованию через 30 сек после входа на страницу
}, 30000);
</script>
```

В течении первых 30 секунд ещё нужно успеть сделать пользовательское действие на странице, иначе вместо восспроизведения получим ошибку в консоли: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first